# Increase rigidbody collider accuracy

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, collision, rigidbody

This is my first time doing any serious physics simulations and I have a doughnut shaped object that needs 100% collider accuracy, but the doughnut hole collides with things, all settings are on default except the weight, how can I increase the accuracy of the collider?

[image: Starting position]

[image: 4 frames later]

Comment: Did you get to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You must change the Shape of your collision object from "Convex Hull" to "Mesh."
With a detailed mesh like that, you may also want to create a simpler torus mesh for collisions and physics, and parent the non-physics higher poly rope mesh to that to speed up physics calculations.

[image: Collision options]

Comment: With mesh it flies off still but in a different direction

Comment: Is the mesh its colliding with also set to Mesh? Also if it's the body, it should have it's Type set to Passive, and the Animated option checked.

Comment: Making both the rope and engineer meshes instead of hulls still has a similar problem